# Does the list of required image formats in Vulkan refer to a certain tiling?

Tags: vulkan

In the "Required Format Support" section of the Vulkan 1.0 spec, the table listing the different image feature bits is titled "Table 41. Feature bits in optimalTilingFeatures". Does this imply that all entries in tables 43 to 53 show only requirements for images with optimal tiling? If not, is it therefore not specified for which tiling the formats have to be supported?

I looked at the 1.3 spec to see whether it's worded differently there, but it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this imply that all entries in tables 43 to 53 show only requirements for images with optimal tiling?

No, it also shows some usages for buffer formats.

But yes, it does not include any requirements for linear tiling. Linear tiling is required to be supported only for transferring data between images. Other uses *can* be supported, but those are the only ones which *must* be supported.